# Adobe Edge Javascript Loop from Start (with Symbols)

Tags: javascript, adobe-edge

I am trying to get an adobe edge animation to loop from the start.
Many tutorials and answers to this say use:

```
sym.play(0);
```

or, add a 'label' at the start and use:

```
sym.play("label");
```

However, this doesn't work for me.

After some digging, it appears that it may be because I am using 'symbols' (to group 4 different 'scenes' to keep everything organised).

The loop does seem to work if I use:

```
sym.getSymbol("Symbol1").play();
```

at the end of the timeline (end of Symbol4). However it will only jump to the start of Symbol1 and play just that one.

What I need is some code which will jump to the start of the timeline and play symbols1 through 4 on repeat forever.

(I tried also getting the stage like this:

```
sym.getComposition().getStage()
```

And playing using that, but to no avail) :(

Thanks

---

UPDATE:

This code seems to replay all, but it only does it one time (so the animation loops 2 times and then stops). Still not there yet! (also this is incredibly hacky!!!)

```
// Replay from the beginning, regardless of current playing state 
if (!sym.getSymbol("Symbol1").isPlaying() && 
    !sym.getSymbol("Symbol2").isPlaying() &&
    !sym.getSymbol("Symbol3").isPlaying() &&
    !sym.getSymbol("Symbol4").isPlaying()
) {
    sym.getSymbol("Symbol1").play(0);
    sym.getSymbol("Symbol2").play(0);
    sym.getSymbol("Symbol3").play(0);
    sym.getSymbol("Symbol4").play(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Add

```
sym.playAll();
```

To the 'complete' action to replay all symbols